# List posts from a category and embed them into a page

Tags: categories

I am using this string to post a list of categories:

```
<?php single_cat_title('You are currently viewing posts we\'ve published under the tag: '); ?>.
```

What I would like to do is embed posts from a specific category on a page.

And, if possible, to limit those posts to the most recent 20.

Is that possible?

I think there are plugins that can do that but I'd rather just use a line of code.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried get_posts?

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly possible. Use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) to search for posts, then output them as you please.

For example, to get 20 posts from the category with the id 4:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'category__in' => 4
        'posts_per_page' => 20
    )
);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo "Here are some posts from that category:";
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

To query other post types or taxonomies, look at the documentation, it has lots of examples.